# How to edit private member of vector in a Class function?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I was working on my work, and it was to input some scores and print out scores, rankings, and pass/fail. I was working with C++ 17, and there was an error on editing my rank.

I've tried to put my vector in a 'setRankPass' function on header file, but it doesn't work at all.

header file

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class Score {
public:
    Score(int score)
        : _score{ score } {
    }
    int getScore() {
        return _score;
    }
    int getRank() {
        return _rank;
    }
    bool getPass() {
        return _pass;
    }
    void setRankPass(const std::vector<int>* scores, int size) {
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; i++) {
            _rank = rank[i];
        }

        double average = static_cast<double>(_rank) / size * 100;
        if (average <= 10) {
            _pass = true;
        }
        else {
            _pass = false;
        }
    }
private:
    int _score{ 0 };
    int _rank{ 0 };
    bool _pass{ false };
};
```

cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Score.h"
using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int enter{ 0 };
        int counter{ 0 };
        vector<Score> v;
        vector<int> s;
        while (enter != -1) {
            cout << "Enter score(-1 to quit): ";
            cin >> enter;
            if (enter == -1)
                break;
            v.push_back(Score(enter));
            counter++;
        }
        int cnt;
        vector<int>rank;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            cnt = 0; 
            for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {
                if (v[i].getScore() < v[j].getScore()) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            rank.push_back(cnt + 1);
        }
        cout << endl;

        for (int a{ 0 }; a < v.size(); a++) {
            v[a].setRankPass(&rank, counter);
        }

        for (int k{ 0 }; k < v.size(); k++) {
            cout << setw(5) << v[k].getScore() << setw(5) << v[k].getRank() << setw(5) << v[k].getPass() << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I had some error on _rank = rank[i]. It was `error E0441 There is no argument list for class template "std::rank"` and `Error C2065 'rank': Undeclared identifier`. I expected that instances on vector rank would be assigned to each _rank. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: @Minjae Lee There is no declaratiion of the variable  _rank and rank used in the class member functions. Your class definition is not complete.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. `vector<int>rank; rank[0]` returns an int which does not have `setRankPass` method. Did you mean to `vector<Score> rank`?

Comment: Sorry guys, I missed uploading my whole source code

Comment: Well, the compiler is right: `rank` isn't declared there. There is no local variable called `rank`, no function parameter called `rank`, and no class member called `rank`. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: You also left out the *real* position of the ill-advised `using namespace std;` that is inconveniently chewing up `rank[i]` and telling you it makes no sense, since [`std::rank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) requires a template argument. `_rank = rank[i]` makes no sense.

Comment: @Quimby Yes, I had meant that. I had edited my codes.

Answer (score 5):

You have no `rank` vector variable in this scope:

```
void setRankPass(const std::vector<int>* scores, int size) {
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; i++) {
        _rank = rank[i];
    }

    double average = static_cast<double>(_rank) / size * 100;
    if (average <= 10) {
        _pass = true;
    }
    else {
        _pass = false;
    }
}
```

You call the function like this:

```
for (int a{ 0 }; a < v.size(); a++) {
    v[a].setRankPass(&rank, counter);
}
```

But the variable you have in the `serRankPass` scope is scores. I assume you meant to do something like that:

```
void setRankPass(const std::vector<int> &rank, int size) { // Pay attention to & and not * (reference instead of pointer) 
    _rank = 0; // initialize to 0 and not junk value
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; i++) {
        _rank += rank[i]; // += instead of = (add and not overwrite)
    }

    double average = static_cast<double>(_rank) / size * 100;
    if (average <= 10) {
        _pass = true;
    }
    else {
        _pass = false;
    }
}
```

Pay attention that after this fix, you'll have to change the following line inside your main:

```
v[a].setRankPass(&rank, counter);
```

to this line:

```
v[a].setRankPass(rank, counter);
```